# My printed list separated by commas has a comma at the star

Tags: python, list

I am writing a small game that will take a randomly generated list, and print it out without the brackets with every value separated by a comma. My only problem is that I have a text string at the beginning and Python is separating the text string and the list with a comma.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
if rollChoice == 6:
        for i in range(6):
            for i in range(4):
                newScore = random.randrange(1, 7)
                abilityScores.append(newScore)
            abilityScores.remove(min(abilityScores))
            for num in abilityScores:
                totalScore += num
            scoreList.append(totalScore)
            totalScore = 0
            abilityScores = []
        print ("Your ability scores are:", *scoreList, sep = ", ")
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Your ability scores are:, 17, 6, 9, 13, 15, 14
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sep` in `print()` means "separate every argument with this separator," and you're passing your header text and all the members of the list as distinct arguments. Try using `.join` instead (although this requires converting your scores to strings for printing):

```py
print("Your ability scores are:", ", ".join([str(score) for score in scoreList]))
```